# SQL Server DECLARE Statement prevents query from executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a query running on SQL Server 2012 that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (   
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.DateEntered DESC) AS RowNumber,
  MANY_FIELDS
  FROM MANY_JOINED_TABLES
  WHERE MANY_CONDITIONS 
) AS sub1
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN (0 + 1) AND (0 + 10)
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

It takes about 3-4 seconds to execute.

I want the 1 and 10 in the last WHERE clause to be variables, but when I use DECLARE before the statement to declare the variables (or even a random variable that's never used) the query just spins and spins and never finishes.

To be clear, this code, which is exactly the same except for the first line never runs:

```
DECLARE @x int

SELECT *
FROM (   
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.DateEntered DESC) AS RowNumber,
  MANY_FIELDS
  FROM MANY_JOINED_TABLES
  WHERE MANY_CONDITIONS 
) AS sub1
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN (0 + 1) AND (0 + 10)
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Is it reproducible always in all other environments? or it is specific to one environment like dev or test?

Comment: theres no reason why that should stop your query. are you sure there isn't something else causing it?

Comment: Actually, yes. It works in our dev environment, so it is environment specific. Sorry, I left that out. The query itself is not the problem; there is something else going on. However, we are able to DECLARE variables used in other queries, so it seems like there is some combination of the query, using DECLARE, and the environment. The database is hosted on AWS.